# Upgrade CI3 to CI4 - configuration files

Tags: codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

In my Codeigniter 3, I have a simple settings.php file that looks something like this:

```
<?php

$config["lang1_HTML"] = "sr-Latn-RS";
$config["lang1_HTML_2"] = "sr-Latn";
$config["lang1_HTML_3"] = "";
$config["lang1_code"] = "SRP";
$config["lang1_flag"] = "/images/flags/rs.png";
$config["sr"] = "lang1";
$config["lang3"] = "en";
$config["lang3_HTML"] = "en-RS";
$config["lang3_HTML_2"] = "en";
$config["lang3_HTML_3"] = "";
$config["lang3_code"] = "ENG";
...
```

Now I want to upgrade this to CI4. Is there any chance to put this file in app\Config without changing it and still be able to access this array?

Or better is it possible to autoload Settings.php and use it like this?

Comment: Are these configurations going to change dynamically? Or are they static hardcoded ?

Comment: @DhavalChheda those are static files. Can be changed with an editor on the site itself. Is there any chance to preserve them in CI4 just like that?

Comment: I don't think you can directly use it in CI4 as it is. You will need to adapt it to CI4 either using it as a singleton service or defining them as constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Upgrading from 3.x to 4.x » Upgrade Configuration](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/installation/upgrade_configuration.html#upgrade-guide)

> **Upgrade Guide**
>
> 1. You have to change the values in the default CI4 config files according to the changes in the CI3 files. The config names are pretty
>    much the same as in CI3.
> 2. If you are using custom config files in your CI3 project you have to create those files as new PHP classes in your CI4 project in
>    **app/Config**. These classes should be in the `Config` namespace and should extend `CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig`.
> 3. Once you have created all custom config classes, you have to copy the variables from the CI3 config into the new CI4 config class as
>    public class properties.
> 4. Now, you have to change the config fetching syntax everywhere you fetch config values. The CI3 syntax is something like
>    `$this->config->item('item_name');`. You have to change this into
>    `config('MyConfigFile')->item_name;`.

##### Step A:

Create a new class `app/Config/Settings.php` in the `Config` namespace that extends `CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig`.

##### Step B:

Copy the variables from the CI3 config into the new CI4 config class as public class properties. I.e:

```php
<?php

namespace Config;

class Settings extends \CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig
{
    public string $lang1_HTML = "sr-Latn-RS";
    public string $lang1_HTML_2 = "sr-Latn";
    public string $lang1_HTML_3 = "";
    public string $lang1_code = "SRP";
    public string $lang1_flag = "/images/flags/rs.png";
    public string $sr = "lang1";

    // ...

}
```

##### Step C:

Change the config fetching syntax everywhere you fetch config values.

I.e: from `$this->config->item('lang1_HTML');` to `config(\Config\Settings::class)->lang1_HTML;`.

---

---

##### Summary:

| CodeIgniter 3.x | CodeIgniter 4.x |
| --- | --- |
| **1. Loading custom config files.** |  |
| [Manual Loading](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html#manual-loading) `$this->config->load('config_filename');` | CodeIgniter 4.x will [automatically look for the files](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/configuration.html#:%7E:text=it%20will%20look%20for%20the%20file%20in%20all%20defined%20namespaces) in all defined namespaces as well as **/app/Config/**. |
| **2. Dealing with name collisions.** |  |
| If you need to load multiple config files, normally they will be merged into one master `$config` array. To avoid collisions you can set the second parameter to `TRUE` and each config file will be stored in an array index corresponding to the name of the config file. Load config file: `$this->config->load('settings', TRUE);` Access item: `$this->config->item('settings')['lang1_HTML']` | You don't have to worry about this since all config files reside in their own individual classes. Access item: `config(\Config\Settings::class)->lang1_HTML` |
| **3. Fetching Config items.** |  |
| `$this->config->item('lang1_HTML');` | `config(\Config\Settings::class)->lang1_HTML` |
| **4. Dynamically setting a config item or changing an existing one.** |  |
| [Set item](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html#setting-a-config-item): `$this->config->set_item('lang1_HTML', 'sr-Cyrl-ME');` Access set item: `$this->config->item('lang1_HTML');` | Set item: `config(\Config\Settings::class)->lang1_HTML = 'sr-Cyrl-ME'` Access set item: `config(\Config\Settings::class)->lang1_HTML` |
| **5.Auto-loading.** |  |
| [Global Auto-loading](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html#auto-loading): Open the *autoload.php* file, located at *application/config/autoload.php*, and add your config file as indicated in the file. `$autoload['config'] = array('settings');` | Global Auto-loading: There is no need to configure this since the [config(...) helper function](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/38be957893425a22319df28b6e9f7039a122fe23/system/Common.php#L190) returns a shared instance of the particular config class by **default**. Hence, you can always access your configs using: `config('config_class_here')->item_name_here;` |

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

first go to app config

```
  public $defaultLocale = 'en';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Negotiate Locale
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * If true, the current Request object will automatically determine the
     * language to use based on the value of the Accept-Language header.
     *
     * If false, no automatic detection will be performed.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $negotiateLocale = true;

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Supported Locales
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * If $negotiateLocale is true, this array lists the locales supported
     * by the application in descending order of priority. If no match is
     * found, the first locale will be used.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    public $supportedLocales = ['en','fa'];
```

go to app create folder language
folder en and folder fa

```
<?php
en/trans.php
return [
    'auth' => [
        'validation' => 'information is not valid',
        'loggedIn' => 'you are already login',
        'notLogIn' => 'you are not login',]];?>
```

fa/trans.php

```
<?php
return [

    'auth' => [
        'validation' => 'خطای  اطلاعات وارد شده',
        'loggedIn' => 'شما قبل وارد شده بودید',
        'notLogIn' => 'شما وارد نشدید',]];?>
```

read  header it send to ci4  --

Accept-Language en
or Accept-Language fa

```
echo lang('trans.auth.validation');
```