# Codeigniter 4 how to load a configuration file from BaseController to use it on all pages

Tags: codeigniter, config, codeigniter-4

In my BaseController I have tried to load my configuration file in various ways, but I cannot find the values

Inside the initController function I tried:

```
$this->myconfig = new \Config\MyConfig;
or
$myconfig = config('\Config\\MyConfig');
or
$myconfig = config('MyConfig');
or
$this->myconfig = config('MyConfig');
```

None of these work

This is my MyConfig test configuration file located in the Config folder

```
namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;

class MyConfig extends BaseConfig
{
    public $ada_default_lang = 'en';
    public $ada_site_name = 'Site name';
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrade CI3 to CI4 - configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70716676/upgrade-ci3-to-ci4-configuration-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to extend your BaseController at all.

Just create your MyConfig.php files following the [upgrade docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_configuration.html):

> In CI4, the configurations are now stored in classes which extend
> CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig.

which you do correctly:

```php
<?php
    namespace Config;
    
    use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;
    
    class MyConfig extends BaseConfig
    {
        public $ada_default_lang = 'en';
        public $ada_site_name = 'Site name';
    }
```

now to access your $ada_default_lang in any controller, you just have to call it inside a controller method with e.g.:

```php
$lang= config('MyConfig')->ada_default_lang );
die($lang); // would halt the program and output 'en'
```

which corresponds to the CI3.x way of something like:    `$this->config->item('ada_default_lang ');`

Comment: Great, you changed my day, can this method also be used for other things like request, session, db connection? If Yes, how?

Comment: @Robert  You can initialize or access those from anywhere in your code using: *Request:*  `$request = \Config\Services::request();`  *Session:*  `$session = session();` *DB:* `$db = db_connect();`

Comment: As suggested by Vickel, I am using this way: service('session')->variable, service('request')->getPost() etc etc, hoping it is the best way to do it

Comment: @Robert `service('$name')` is [behind the scenes the **same** as](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/b6866de9add4542233443aa10dbfd4e30d0466ad/system/Common.php#L958) `\Config\Service::$name()`. I personally prefer the latter because it allows my IDE to *navigate to the declaration* quite easily. Lastly, `service('session')` is [behind the scenes the **same** as](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/b6866de9add4542233443aa10dbfd4e30d0466ad/system/Common.php#L930) `session()`

Comment: Ok, perfect, thanks ;)